# Воспроизвести аудио сигнал при push уведомлении?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, push

Как сделать, при выводе push уведомления на сайте, чтобы был аудио сигнал, как например в вк?

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted(){
        window.Echo.private('user_notif')
            .listen('UserNotification', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });

    },
    methods: {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

решил

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted(){
        window.Echo.private('user_notif')
            .listen('UserNotification', (e) => {
                var audio = new Audio('/sounds/push.mp3'); // path to file
                audio.play();
                console.log(e);
            });

    },
    methods: {

    }
});
```